# DDay iCalendar DTEND in UTC

Tags: c#, icalendar, dday

I have a date in UTC that I would like to use directly in my DDay iCalendar, but I cannot figure out how to tell the library that the time is in UTC.  I believe it's a matter of appending a Z at the end of my time, but I can't figure out how to specify DDay should suffix with a "Z":

"Good" iCalendar Date

```
DTEND:20120110T223000Z
```

"Bad" iCalendar Date

```
DTEND:20120119T170000
```

Comment: [Here](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/dateTime.html) is a link to the section of the ICal spect that described *how* dates are formatted. It is pretty clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how we implement it:

```
string sValue = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString(@"yyyyMMdd\THHmmss\Z");
```